# Automatically check if local files are latest version in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have three screens in my app, in UITabBarViewController.

On one screen, I have a UITableView listing those files that are in the apps document folder.

I am using CoreData to store an associated object for each file.

These objects have a property of version number and a method to check a remote repository.

Therefore, checking if the file is out of date is as easy as local version number < remote version number.

My question is, what is the best way to manage these background checks? I have been able to check when the view loads, but that blocks the UI and I want this check to run in the background at a set interval.

My limited experience tells me that this is a case for GCD and there is some kind of interval to set? How do I get this timer running when the app is started? How do I get it running and updating in the background?

Thanks!

Comment: not really clear what your issue is. show the code you currently have - why does it block the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use thread. this will help you to run your task in background without disturbing your current views UI and functional activity.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in
             // Your task code
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An access to remote repository anyway takes time. So I think you should use asynchrone request to repository and show spinner (activity indicator view) for user until check pass. Nice practice is specify how much files remote repository must check.
Table view anyway show only a portion of information on screen. You should request, for example, first ten files versions. Then more ten files and so on.
I dont know your logic but check file version and update file info in table should not take long.
If you absolute new in iOS read about NSURLSession class or AFNetworking library.